# Demo Game for fmod experimentation

Tags: gameaudio, fmod, wwise

Comrades!

I have recently decided to push myself to the next level of audioness.  Pushing my Sound Design skills, getting into Field Recording...  learning Interactive Audio.... wait..

So, learning fmod and wwise is all well and good but how am I suppose to know if my sound defs, my events, or my music actually work in a game?

Perhaps I missed something in the tutorial files provided, but I was hoping there would be a game I could test my work in, make sure I am heading in the right direction.

I found some good discussions on gamedev.net, and a few links, but I don't know C++ (yet?)  Is there a place I can download a game to test my audio in, or is there a good site/ resource to supplement my fmod/wwise tutorials?

Comment: Hi @Audioandy, I'm searching for help with creating a Game Audio Sound Design showreel as well. What path did you take in the end, and how did it turn out?

Answer (score 3):

Audiokinetic has a game called Cube that you can download (same page as the rest of the Wwise downloads) and drop your sounds into.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Crysis you can download the SDK for free, it comes with a certain version of fmod that works with the CryEngine2 editor and you can implement your sound on either the maps that come with the game or something you create. I don't really know much about this tbh so hopefully some one else can help out a little more.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Audioandy

I would advise you not to waste your time for this.
Knowledge of Fmod or Wwise - in the first place – it is the work in real game. I mean not just the game, I mean the process of game development. Specifically when you work with sound priorities and secondly when you implement your sound in game. I'm not talking about creating simple objects like minigun or auto engine with rpm which you can find in tutorial material. I'm talking about the process when you invent and decide which methods will be working  in this case best of all.

Both these possibilities won't be available for you in Crysis SDK and Wwise Cube.

Do not exaggerate the meaning of Fmod or Wwise. It is a great tools but you should start learn it when you will be working on real game. Employers often point this item in the requirements of new vacancy. But it's mean that you have real experience. Cryengine SDK and Akcube it's just the familiarity with the foundation.

Sorry my English.

Comment: I think you make some good points in this answer. I have spent alot of time learning these software apps and run into the same dead end as @audioandy. 

But, I do think that having a knowledge of the software and how it works (maybe even a sample of it in action), shows to a potential employer that you are interested in using it and working in the industry. The real learning can start from there.

Answer (score 1):

FMod Sandbox is great when you're auditioning. Also, there's a tool named "Audition 3D" at Tools menu of FMod.

Both are great whn you need quick Auditioning.

Also, FMod has Network Auditioning tool which able to connect another device (Like XBOX) and recieve it's current audio with their exact parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the same sort of thing soon too, and create some Showreel material to help my push into game audio!

You can [download](http://www.udk.com/download) the UDK (Unreal Development Kit) too for free (or it comes with copies of Unreal Tournament etc). There are plenty of tutorials to throw together a very simple level, and then plenty of tutorials on how to then use Wwise with it. .

C++ isn't necessary (although no doubt handy) unless you want to get into the Audio Programming, which is a seperate role from Sound / Audio Design. From what I've seen, many companies like experience with the Unreal engine, as well as others like Source, as they're very widely used game engines.

Answer (score 0):

To test FMOD content you could download FMOD Sandbox from [the Firelight Technologies downloads page](http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download#FMODSandbox), but that's really more of an auditioning tool than anything truly game-like. Other than that, the FMOD UE3 integration could allow you to try putting events into game levels, but you need to be a registered Unreal 3 Engine Developer to get access to it.